# CSS feature detection with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, modernizr, feature-detection, styled-components

I typically use Modernizr to feature-detect for CSS features like flex-box support and fall back to older methods if unsupported:

```
.mz-flexbox {
  // use flex
}

.mz-noflexbox {
  // use floats
}
```

How would one accomplish something similar with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) with something like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) where classes are added to the `<html>` element to indicate feature support?

My only thought at this point is importing components in my "App.js" and using `injectGlobal` to target them:

```
import MyComponent from './components/my-component';

injectGlobal`
  .mz-flexbox {
    ${MyComponent} {
      // use flex
    }
  }
`;
```

It appears `@supports` would be a sweet solution, but I do care about Internet Explorer, so this is not a solution for this project.

Lastly, I'm not sure if this is a good way to do this, but would something like this work for feature detection? I'm not 100% on what gets compiled with styled-components and what can be calculated at run-time:

```
styled.div`
  ${window.Modernizr.flexbox && css`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  `}
`;
```

Will that work for detection at run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just query the classList of the `hmtl` tag.

`const modern = document.querySelector('html').classList`

Then just check to see if the feature class you're looking for is in that list. For example:

```
if (modern.contains('noflexbox') {
  // Adjust as per usual
}
```

It's all just JavaScript :D

A better method, however, would be to use the Modernizr API directly, rather than relying on the presence of classes.  So your code would look more like:

```
if(Modernizr.someFeature) { ... }
```

Check out the [modernizr docs](https://modernizr.com/docs#helper-methods)

RE: your last example - yep, that'll work, assuming you're bundling modernizr as a dependency with the rest of your javascript.  There are other approaches in the docs for setting up feature *tests*, which should help reduce condition duplication in your styled strings